# How does Prometheus get refresh tokens from sidecar program

Tags: oauth-2.0, prometheus, bearer-token, refresh-token

I have Prometheus setup on a Kubernetes Pod, which also has a sidecar that will connect to OAuth server and get a bearer token for the targets from where Prometheus is trying to fetch data.
What is happening is that the token expires after 2 weeks and then I have to restart the Pod for getting the new token work with Prometheus. I believe that the sidecar is getting the new token but that token is not getting updated in Prometheus, and so I have to restart the pod to get that new token working.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days Prometheus reads the token from a `bearer_token_file` on every HTTP request, so this should just work once the file is updated.

Comment: The thing is there are no HTTP requests, when I restart the Kube pod the token gets updated.